# Why can Toast be instantiated without the new keyword?

Tags: java, android

So for the Toast class, it can apparently be written like this :

```
Toast toastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
toastMessage.show();
```

Why exactly is it possible for toastMessage to be instantiated and used as an object without the new keyword?

How can toastMessage be instantiated by a method?

Comment: Not sure... But probably in the same way like `SomeClass.getInstance()` for singleton classes??? The `makeText()` method is probably creating a new object or returning an already existing object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing special about `Toast` here. You're just calling a static method which creates an instance (or could possibly reuse an existing one - it's an implementation detail). This is a pattern you'll see all over the place - `Calendar.getInstance()`, for example. Sometimes you can call the constructor instead, sometimes you can *only* create an instance via a static method.

Unless something craft is going on under the hood, it's likely that *somewhere* in the implementation there'll be a call to a constructor. Here's a trivial example:

```
public final class CreateViaMethod {
    private final String name;

    private CreateViaMethod(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static CreateViaMethod newInstance(String name) {
        return new CreateViaMethod(name);
    }
}
```

There are various reasons why an API designer *might* want to do this. For example, there might be several "creation" methods with the same parameter types, but different names, e.g.

```
public static Duration fromSeconds(int seconds)
public static Duration fromMinutes(int minutes)
public static Duration fromHours(int hours)
```

... you couldn't have three overloaded constructors there, but you can give *methods* different names.

Answer (score 2):

This is a beginner question, but quite a good one. Let me give you a general answer.

let's suppose you have `MyClass`, like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {} //constructor

    public static MyClass generateMyClass() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

}
```

You can use `MyClass.generateMyClass()` which creates a `MyClass` instance and returns it:

```
MyClass myClassInstance = MyClass.generateMyClass();
```

The same goes with `Toast.makeText`. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

Because Toast.makeText() is a static method returning a Toast object.

[Toast - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))